# Google App Not verified while exporting contact

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, google-api, google-authentication

> I have created an app to export user's google contacts but when i redirect to that URL it show APP isn't verfied

```
define('IMPORT_URL','https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=something.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.somewebsite.com/Home/callback&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly&response_type=code');
```

Answer (score 0):

It means your app isn't verified by Google,

You should follow these instructions:

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification

as it explains what to do to to have it verified by Google.

You should be able to still continue the process but if you plan to make it public I'd advise you follow these

Comment: Already fill out this form

Comment: Well, with the few information we have it's the only help we can provide

Comment: @user3534476 it can take weeks to become verified you will need to wait.

Comment: @Dalm already months past still showing that error